Spellcheck I Before E
Background
As the old saying goes, "I before E, except after C". Whilst we already know exactly how true that saying is, I am a stickler for sayings, especially those that rhyme. I want you to build me an ultra-simple spellchecker which confirms whether or not this vital  rule was followed.
The Challenge
Given a string, determine if it:

Never contains the sub-string cie
Never contains the sub-string ei that is not immediately following c

The Rules

Input will be a string of 0 or more lowercase letters and nothing else.
Standard IO applies
Standard Loopholes are forbidden

Test Cases
ceicel    => TRUE
friend    => TRUE
iiee      => TRUE
ie        => TRUE
ceie      => TRUE
eceii     => TRUE
neighbour => FALSE
weight    => FALSE
deficient => FALSE
ieie      => FALSE
ei        => FALSE


Suggested test case eight => FALSE (or another string starting with ei besides test-case "ei" itself).

Suggested test case string => TRUE where neither ei nor ie is present.

JavaScript (V8), 26 bytes
x=>!/cie|[^c]ei/.test(0+x)

Try it online!
Same length x=>!/cie|(?<!c)ei/.test(x)

Vyxal, 152 bitsv2, 19 bytes
`cie`c¬?`.?ei`Ẏ`cei`=A∧

Try it Online!
Bitstring:
01101101101000001011111100110011000001010100101101100011101000011110111001011111100111000011101110101010000001000101100101110100001001011010101010010011

The footer converts the 0/1 to FALSE/TRUE respectively for the test cases.
Returns true if cie isn't present and all instances of ei are preceded by a c.
Explained
`cie`c¬?`.?ei`Ẏ`cei`=A∧­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
`cie`c¬                  # ‎⁡Is "cie" absent in the input
                      ∧  # ‎⁢And
                     A   # ‎⁣Are all
        `.?ei`Ẏ          # ‎⁤Instances of `ei` with the (optional) letter that comes beforehand
               `cei`=    # ‎⁢⁡Equal to cei? 


Created with the help of Luminespire.

JavaScript (V8), 35 bytes
x=>/^((?!(?<!c)ei|cie).)*$/.test(x)

Try it online!
Admittedly identical to the regex solution ATaco found in chat but we came to our conclusions independently. And mine is in funny javascript.
x=>/^((?!(?<!c)ei|cie).)*$/.test(x)  //full program
x=>/                      /.test(x)  //js regex boilerplate
    ^                    $           //within the entire string
     (                .)*            //for every character,
                                     //(if there are any)
      (?!            )               //so long as the next few
                                     //characters are not
                 |                     //either
                  cie                    //"cie"
               ei                        //or an "ei"
         (?<!c)                          //that isnt after "c"
                                     //return true, qed


Zsh, 26 24 bytes
-2 bytes, thanks to @GammaFunction
${1:/(*cie|(|*[^c])ei)*}

Try it Online!  
26 bytes
Returns 127 for truthy (input obeys the rule), 0 for falsey.

Restructure as ${1:/(*cie|(|*[^c])ei)*} for 24 bytes.

APL+WIN, 44 bytes
Prompts for string. Outputs 1=true, 0=false
3=+/2 4 5≠(4⍴2)⊥+/¨ 'cei' 'cie' 'ei' 'ie'⍷¨⊂⎕

Try it online! Thanks to Dyalog Classic

Python 3, 46 bytes
lambda s:(q:=s.count)("cie")+q("ei")<=q("cei")

Try it online!
Checks that the count of cie's is zero, and that the the count of ei's equal that of cei's. These are combined into one inequality as cie's + ei's <= cei's. If we may output true/false flipped, we can negate the >= to < to save 1.
50 bytes
lambda s:not re.search("cie|(?<!c)ei",s)
import re

Try it online!
A regex solution. The outer not converts match objects to False, and Nones indicating no match to False. If we could do truthy/falsy reversed, we could use re.compile for 43 bytes:
import re
re.compile("cie|(?<!c)ei").search

Try it online!

Perl 5 -p, 20 bytes
$_=!/cie|(^|[^c])ei/

Try it online!

05AB1E, 20 16 bytes
¬ìAε„eiN<iR}«}åà

Outputs an inverted boolean (0 for truthy; 1 for falsey).
Try it online or verify all test cases.
Explanation:
¬         # Get the first character of the (implicit) input-string
 ì        # Prepend this letter to the input-string
  A       # Push the alphabet
   ε      # Map over each letter:
    „ei   #  Push string "ei"
    N<i   #  If the 0-based index is 2:
       R  #   Reverse it to "ie"
      }«  #  After the if-statement, append it to the letter
   }å     # After the map: check for each whether it's a substring in the input
     à    # Pop and check if any is truthy
          # (after which the result is output implicitly)

The ¬ì is for edge-cases that start with ei (or test case "ei" itself).

sed -rn, 20 18 bytes
/^ei|[^c]ei|cie/q1

Takes one string on stdin, and returns exit code 0 (1) for strings that do (do not) follow the rule.
Try it online!

Charcoal, 19 bytes
¬∨№θcie⁻⌕Ａθei⁺¹⌕Ａθc

Try it online! Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs a Charcoal boolean, i.e. - for ie and cei only, nothing if ei or cie. Explanation:
  №                 Count of
    cie             Literal string `cie`
   θ                In input string
 ∨                  Logical Or
        ⌕Ａ          Find All
           ei       Literal string `ei`
          θ         In input string
       ⁻            Set difference
               ⌕Ａ   Find All
                  c Literal string `c`
                 θ  In input sring
             ⁺      Vectorised Plus
              ¹     Literal integer `1`
¬                   Logical Not
                    Implicitly print

Note that using the newer version of Charcoal on ATO I could have saved a byte by using Incremented() instead of Plus(1, ).

Python 3, 59 bytes
Just another boring Python solution with re. None is falsy, an re.Match object is truthy. Basically, the regex confirms the string has no cies, and then any eis without a c behind. It matches the string if both conditions succeeded.
lambda n:re.match("^(?!.*cie)(?!.*(?<!c)ei).*",n)
import re

Try it online!
If you're confused about the True output, expand the header and footer in case it doesn't show. The footer contains some testing code to assert that the function does indeed work according to the test cases.

Google Sheets, 32 bytes
=1-regexmatch(1&A1,"cie|[^c]ei")

Uses the same regex as many others. Gets 0 for false and 1 for true. Remove the 1- bit to get true for false and false for true and save two bytes.


Bash, 25 22 bytes
egrep "[^c]ei|cie|^ei"

Try it online!  
25 bytes
Returns 1 for truthy (input obeys the rule), 0 for falsy.

egrep "[^c]ei|cie|^ei" for 22 bytes since you can ignore STDOUT

Uiua, 20 24 bytes (thx to Jan Blumschein's correction)
¬±⧻regex"cie|[^c]ei|^ei"

Try this online!
Explanation:
¬±⧻regex"cie|[^c]ei|^ei"
   regex"cie|[^c]ei|^ei" => find matches of illegal combos
  ⧻                      => is there a match? (length of matches > 0)
¬±                       => signum as a boolean value and negate


Input starting with "ei" (test cases "ei", "eight") seems not to be classified as it should  be
